# NavigationComponents retaining fragment state without advanced example

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a fragment that holds a list , but when I navigate from `FragmentA()` to `FragmentB()` with

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_b)
```

And come back, the view recreates itself and so on the list is duplicated with the contents of the previous loaded list

What I have tried

1. Clearing the list before adding it
2. onSaveInstanceState does not work for fragments

Here when I set this data it is show properly on `FragmentA()` but if I go to `FragmentB()` and comeback , it is duplicated and the view is also recreated, I need a way to keep this fragment alive when navigating back

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        if(myList.isEmpty()){
            showEmptyContainer()
        }else{
            adapter.setItems(myList)
        }

}
```

Comment: post your set `setItems()` method

Comment: is just .add on the list and notifySetDataChanged

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving the setup of the list in onCreate() and then declaring a variable

```
val view:View?= null
```

and asking in onCreateView if this is null, if it is , inflate the layout, if not continue